# Не работает zip2john на kali linux

Tags: python, kali-linux

Пишу:

```
sudo apt-get install john
```

Пишет, что установлена последняя версия

А когда пишу

zip2john (путь к архиву) (путь для сохранения результата)

Выдает:

zip2john команда не найдена, что делать?

Comment: А не нужно ли из какой-то определенной папки вызывать? Типа $HOME/bin ?

Comment: Уже из всех возможных перепробовал :(

Comment: Осталось попробовать `sudo zip2john`

Comment: sudo zip2john Не помогло